# what does the following C code translate to?

Tags: c

So I have a for loop which goes like this:

```
for(span=N>>1;span;span>>=1)
```

I am assuming the start and end conditions are equivalent to as follows:

```
span = N>>1; //right shift N by 1 and initialize to span
while(span!=0)
{
 span = span >> 1;
}
```

However it seems a little bizarre in the context of my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks right to me...

Comment: Unless the context is stated; no one can help to tell if its bizarre or not. But the loop as such looks ok to me

Comment: `it seems a little bizarre in the context of my code`... what's the context?

Comment: Assuming `span` is unsigned, right-shifting it will predictably and eventually make all its bits 0. Your interpretation is spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every iteration you are dividing the variable span by 2 until it reaches 0.

so if initially N = 8, then values for span will be 4, 2, 1, 0 -> exit loop

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

- The initializer sets `span = N >> 1`, right-shifting N by 1.
- The loop condition is `span`, which is equivalent to `span != 0`.
- Every time the loop comes around, `span` is right-shifted again by 1.

In the context of positive integers, this is equivalent to `for(span=N/2;span>0;span/=2)`. However, without knowing your particular context I cannot comment whether this is or is not bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet...Yes as far as you have shown the code, your interpretation stands firm and good.